# Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
        if ($this->sort) {
            $products = $this->products;
            if ($this->sort == "price-asc" || $this->sort == "price-desc") {
                $products->join('product_units', 'product_units.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                    ->orderBy('product_units.price_per_unit', explode('-', $this->sort)[1]);
                $ids = $products->pluck('company_id')->toArray();
                $this->query->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, ' . implode(', ', $ids) . ') ASC');
            }
            if ($this->sort == 'latest') {
                $products->orderBy('price_updated_at');
                $ids = $products->pluck('company_id')->toArray();
                $this->query->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, ' . implode(', ', $ids) . ') ASC');
            }
        }
```

Hi, this is a part of filterProduct,php file which filters products according to price, but I see this error :

> "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `products` inner join `product_units` on `product_units`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where `category_id` = 4 and `products`.`deleted_at` is null order by `product_units`.`price_per_unit` desc)",

How I can fix it, and I should mention that product_units and product has a one to many relationship

I want to sort products according to id column from products table in orderByRaw query, or if there is another query I can use,

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for answering I defined $products in this way   $products = $this->products;

Comment: @TimLewis Sorry Tim, I edited my question, I think reason of having this problem is joining two tables which both have id column and in orderByRaw query it is not clear which id column should be used.

Comment: That's what I said in my now-deleted comments... Which query is causing the issue? The `$products` one, or `$this->query`? I tried to get you to show your full code so I could determine that, but you still didn't include how you're defining `$this->products`... If the issue is with `FIELD(id`, then do `FIELD(products.id`, but I don't think that's the one that's triggering your error.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line

> $this->query->orderByRaw('FIELD (id, ' . implode(', ', $ids) . ') ASC');

Specify the id column with the table.

Comment: Thanks for answering if I use name of table like products.id then I have another problem :
products.id column not found
How can I specify id column ?